# This is a question about how to recover mongodb composed of shards

Tags: mongodb

The current situation is that the db is corrupted by killing and raising the process using linux command kill rather than the normal method of mongodb.

If I had used the shutdown command, it would not have been corrupted.

It is composed of shards and consists of rs1, rs2, and rs3 as servers of the generation.

Below is the shard server configuration information

mongos : 192.11.4

rs1(192.11.1) - A : rs1 shard1(192.11.1:2017) / rs2 shard2(192.11.2:2018) / rs3 shard3(291.11.3:2019)

rs2(192.11.2) - b : rs1 shard1(192.11.1:2017) / rs2 shard2(192.11.2:2018) / rs3 shard3(291.11.3:2019)

rs3(192.11.3) - c : rs1 shard1(192.11.1:2017) / rs2 shard2(192.11.2:2018) / rs3 shard3(291.11.3:2019)

In the case of rs2 and rs3, it was repaired through mongod --repair, but rs1 is not --repaired and is not repaired.

Database on rs1(192.11.1) - A is not running

Is there any way to recover rs1?

Comment: The shard layout is not clear to me, can you please run `db.adminCommand("getShardMap").map` and post the output? Which of them are corrupted?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am currently unable to enter the admin command. The rs1 server is not coming up. rs1 is not running, so mongos is not attached. rs1 is broken. I wonder if there is any way.

Comment: I would expect messages to appear in the MongoDB error log that might be useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: As said, I don't get your setup. When you say "rs1 is corrupted" - did you check all three hosts? As far as I see, the data is replicated three times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check the log file in more detail.